# How can I use data from an API immediately with useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm getting images via an API that is fetched in a `useEffect` hook.
I want to store a random image into an object array and display it immediately when loading the side.

The problem is the `useEffect` hook is executed after rendering so the function which gets the random image throws an error.

```
const [allImages, setAllImages] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
    .then((response) => response.json()          
    .then((data) => setAllImages(data.data.memes));
}, []);

const [memes, setMemes] = useState([
    { img: getRandomImg() },
  ]);

function getRandomImg() {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * allImages.length);
    console.log("3");
    return allImages[randomIndex].url;
  }
```

First thought was to just return the `getRandomImg` function if there are no images but nothing is displayed then.

```
function getRandomImg() {
        if (allImages.length === 0) return;
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * allImages.length);
        console.log("3");
        return allImages[randomIndex].url;
      }
```

I found a solution that works by adding another `useEffect` with a dependencie on `allImages`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setAllImages(data.data.memes));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (allImages.length > 0) {
      addImage();
    }
  }, [allImages]);

  const [memes, setMemes] = useState([]);

  function getRandomImg() {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * allImages.length);
    console.log("3");
    return allImages[randomIndex].url;
  }

  const addImage = () => {
    setMemes((prevMemes) => [
      ...prevMemes,
      {
        img: getRandomImg(),
      },
    ]);
  };
```

But this seems more like a workaround and this is sometimes adding two pictures instead of one.

Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Try using useLayoutEffect hook, this executed before the render.
Documentation:
[useLayoutEffect](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proposed solution is fine, I would do it this way:

```
const [allImages, setAllImages] = useState([]);
const [memes, setMemes] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
    .then((response) => response.json()          
    .then((data) => {
          setAllImages(data.data.memes)
          const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * allImages.length);
          setMemes([{img: data.data.memes[randomIndex].url}])
          // do not use allImages in setMemes, as setState is async
          // and the new state of allImages will not be ready yet.
    });
}, []);
```

If you would need the images to be ready before the page is rendered, you can use useLayoutEffect as proposed by Sebastian.

Answer (score 0):

Does `memes` need to be in state? If not, `useMemo` may be a better fit here:

```
const [allImages, setAllImages] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
    .then((response) => response.json()          
    .then((data) => setAllImages(data.data.memes));
}, [setAllImages]);

const memes = useMemo(() => {
    if (allImages.length === 0){
      return null;
    }

    return { img: getRandomImg() },
  }, [allImages]);

function getRandomImg() {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * allImages.length);
    console.log("3");
    return allImages[randomIndex].url;
  }
```

The dependency array `[allImages]` passed as the second parameter to `useMemo` will cause the in-line function (the first parameter) to be executed one time every time `allImages` is updated in state (via the `setAllImages` callback). Note that at first, `allImages` won't have a value because the `fetch()` promise hasn't resolved yet, so you have to guard against that. Usually that means rendering `null` or an empty string the first time, and re-rendering once the data has been fetched.